# Removing duplicates from multiple arrays at once

Tags: javascript, array

This (working) code is supposed to return a new array that consists of elements of **both** arrays that were not marked as duplicates (*find duplicates in both arrays, remove such elements from both arrays and create an array from the leftovers, if any*)

Is there a way to simplify this function?

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr1_filtered, arr2_filtered;

    arr1_filtered = arr1.filter(function (v) {
        return arr2.indexOf(v) == -1;
    });

    arr2_filtered = arr2.filter(function (v) {
        return arr1.indexOf(v) == -1;
    });

    return arr1_filtered.concat(arr2_filtered);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate from resulting array too?

Comment: yes, from both of them and then combine non-duplicates in one new array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function on `Array.prototype` that'll accept an array and filter the array by checking if the element is in the other array.

```
// Define a function on Array prototype
Array.prototype.arrayDiff = function (arr) {
    return this.filter(function (v) {
        return arr.indexOf(v) === -1;
    });
};

function diff(arr1, arr2) {
    // 1. Remove elements that are in arr2 from arr1
    //    i.e. arr1.arrayDiff(arr2)
    // 2. Remove elements that are in arr1 from arr2
    //    i.e. arr2.arrayDiff(arr1)
    // 3. Concat the result of both the arrays

    return arr1.arrayDiff(arr2).concat(arr2.arrayDiff(arr1));
}
```

```js
// Define a function on Array prototype
Array.prototype.removeDuplicates = function(arr) {
  return this.filter(function(v) {
    return arr.indexOf(v) === -1;
  });
};

function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.removeDuplicates(arr2).concat(arr2.removeDuplicates(arr1));
}

var arr = diff([1, 3, 4, 2, 5], [2, 45, 7, 42, 1, 6]);
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```